# Should Radio/Audio questions be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Rory had said he would mark this question as off-topic:

[Radio stops playing when I change volume](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16330/radio-stops-playing-when-i-change-volume)

There have been questions answered about audio in the past ... I'm not seeing as why this is off topic. I mean, by these standards, tires would be off-topic because they are a mechanical thing on the car, just a piece of rubber. Audio equipment is part of the vehicle itself, so IMHO, it should be on-topic. Yes, there is a cross-over into the grey area of electronics or audiophilia, but this happens quite a bit on most SE sites. Should questions like these be off-topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The help section states

> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles **and
>   their accessories** (emphasis mine)

This question is definitely on topic, it's a factory installed accessory, so to me there is no question. Not saying that an aftermarket radio would be off topic, just trying to say that anything that comes installed from the factory on a vehicle should be on topic.

Factory installed Wi-Fi hot spots for example, would be on topic. In my option anything the dealership service department would normally work on would be on topic.

Comment: Thanks, Larry. I was thinking I was out in the breeze on this one.

Comment: OK - that makes sense. I just thought it felt really off topic.