# Are electronic vehicle accessories questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

**Question**

If I ask a question about an electronic vehicle accessory would the question be on topic?

**Example Question**

How do I open an app with the Kinivo BTC455 Bluetooth adapter?*

**Example car accessories**

- Bluetooth adapter ([link](https://kinivo.com/product/btc455-hands-free-bluetooth-car-adapter/))
- real time car diagnositc adapters ([link](http://www.plxdevices.com/Kiwi-2-OBD2-Wireless-Bluetooth-Diagnostic-Scanner-p/897346002573.htm))
- DashCams ([link](http://www.spytecinc.com/g1w-1080p-hd-car-dash-camera.html))
- 3rd party GPS

---

*Other Info*

I searched through meta for car accessories and I was not able to find the question, I am a bit surprised it did not come up before this, so I apologise (and will close this) if I missed the topic in my search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer this question by directing you to [my question](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/should-radio-audio-questions-be-off-topic).

Accessories are on-topic as per the help section:

> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and **their accessories** 
>   (emphasis mine)

I realize the other question has to do with *factory installed* accessories, but I don't see why it shouldn't extend to user installed accessories as well. Does that mean *all* accessory questions are on-topic ... probably not. It's going to be a case-by-case basis. Your example of the *Kinivo BTC455 Bluetooth adapter* is probably an RTFM (Read the F-ing Manual) situation and would not be too helpful of a question. On the other hand, *how to attach the same reader* would definitely be on topic, IMHO.

Comment: Interesting this makes sense also, due to the difference in wording I can see why your question got missed my initial search. My example question was only meant as an example but yes if the answer was in the manual it would not be a good question regardless to it being ontopic or not.

Comment: After some though (as both sides have good points) I have marked this answer as there is some precedent for the yes side of the question.

Comment: @Gram - I hope my comment wasn't rude as it wasn't meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw in my 2 cents and say: No. If I put a tablet in my car does it qualify as an accessory?

The products you listed are completely separate from the vehicle. You could try the product documentation, the product user forums, or a car enthusiast forum. This site is about the vehicle and it's underlying systems.

P.S. The diagnostic adapter you linked is grossly overpriced. It's cheaper to purchase an ELM327 adapter and the Torque app.

Comment: I am going to give the question a bit longer to make sure everyone has the chance to post their options, but what you said about the table makes sense to me. Also thanks for the diagnostic adapter recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

When I hear the term accessory I think more like a tow hitch or high powered spot lights.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the discussion topic slightly to clarify.